# SQL query, select rows with one column of the same value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm quite a beginner with SQL, I met a query which need help. 
I have two following schema:

- Customers(cID, cname)
- Trade(goodsID, cID)

I want to find customers who ONLY buy one kind of goods, which means, for the same cID, it could only paired with the same goodsID in tuples of Trade.

For example:

```
+----------+-------+
| cID      |goodsID|
+----------+-------+
| 1000     | 1     |
| 1000     | 1     |
| 1000     | 1     |
| 1001     | 2     |
| 1001     | 3     |
| 1002     | 4     |
+----------+-------+
```

The output should be:

```
+----------+
| cID      |
+----------+
| 1000     |
| 1002     |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a simple query like this:

```
SELECT CID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT goodsID) = 1;
```

Comment: Wasnt sure if could use distinct that way. Now I know for next time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cID, count(goodsID)
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT cID, goodsID
       FROM table1
     ) as T
GROUP BY cID
HAVING count(goodsID) = 1
```